# how to determine number of clusters of image dynamically in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn

so my problem is that I follow [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/11/7/988) in order to segment a hand out of an image, my problem is that in the paper he stated that we first segment the image into 2 clusters using GMM against (skin-like color and background) then we segment the resulting image using 3 clusters (skin-like color, skin color, black background) but my problem is that some images segments correctly using 3 clusters and other images is segmented in a wrong way so how to determine dynamically in the code the best K between 2 and 3, here are some example:

### Original image 1

[image]

### image 1 segmented using K = 2##

[image]

### image 1 segmented using K = 3##

[image]

### Original image 2

[image]

### image 2 segmented using K = 2##

[image]

### image 2 segmented using K = 3##

[image]

same algorithm same code same every thing but the number of clusters is different, so how to choose dynamically (by code) whether K = 2 or K = 3, is there any idea that could help me ?